# How to manually adjust QGIS raster histogram X-values?

Tags: qgis, raster, histogram

**Background:**

At 3.20.2 I am unable to manually adjust the raster histogram minimum and maximum X-values, as shown in the screen shot below.

There are fill-in boxes (within the red graphic box) which lead me to believe that a manual adjustment is possible.  However, changing those values does not change the histogram image.

Changing the options in the Prefs/Actions dropdown has no effect, either.

In summary, I want to control the *numeric spread* of the X-axis by manually setting the lower and upper values.  In the screenshot below, I would like to leave the lower value unchanged, while increasing the maximum value to +0.20.

**EDIT: Why do I need to do this?**

I have 12 rasters (covering the same spatial extent), each depicting NDVI at a separate time.  Because NDVI changes with the growing season, the resulting 12 histograms have differing min-X and max-X values.  I need to sequentially display the histograms, and it would really help the viewer interpret those histograms if they all displayed *the same* min-X and max-X range.

I have determined the absolute min value and max value for all 12 rasters, which I would use for all the histograms.

**Question:**

How to manually set the max/min X-values for QGIS raster histograms?

[image]

**Solution:**

Babel's answer was correct.  For posterity, here are the steps that worked for me at 3.20.3:

**Original histogram:**

I want to change the default min/max values within the red box.

[image]

**Process:**

Click the *Prefs/Actions* button and make sure the *Zoom to Min/Max* and *Update Style to Min/Max* options are checked on.  Click the *Reset* button (1), which clears the min/max boxes (2).

[image]

Type in  the new Min/Max values.  **Important:** Don't press the *Enter* button after typing the new values.  I used the Tab button after entering each value.  Voila!  The histogram is updated with the new Min/Max values.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click `Prefs/Actions`, then activate `Zoom to min/max`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default, bands are stretched to Min/Max. You can adjust this from the symbology tab.

[image: Band Rendering Options in QGIS]

If you leave the render type in Singleband Gray, you can simply input your desired Min/Max values and update the settings to User Defined. You also have the option to do a singleband pseudocolor, where you are also able to define the number of classes, the breakpoints (including stretching), and the color ramps.