# Adjusting raster histogram frequency axis

Tags: qgis, raster, histogram

I am trying to create multiple raster histograms for comparison in QGIS. Therefore standardised axis are desirable. All the rasters contain the same number of pixels.

Adjusting histogram X-axis is doable following a previous question: [How to manually adjust QGIS raster histogram X-values?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411700/how-to-manually-adjust-qgis-raster-histogram-x-values)
How can you adjust the Y-axis too? Failing that, what alternative methods would you suggest?